# How to check a username and password pair from SQL Server in asp.net webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My login button's code is

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Name], [Password] FROM [dbo].[user]", connection);

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                // something goes there
            }

            if ()    // admin authentication 
            {
               Session["User_ID"] = nameTextBox.Text;
               Response.Redirect("~/AdminPanel.aspx");
            }
            else if()     // user authentication
            {
               Session["User_ID"] = nameTextBox.Text;
               Response.Redirect("~/UserPanel.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Login` table, I have columns `UserID`, `UserName`, `Password`. There are nametextBox and passwordTextBox to get the UserName & password. Please help me since I'm stuck on the condition of user login.

Comment: You can put condition in query ?

Comment: your code is very messy... first, you loop trough reader (doing something, for something(?)) and then check for something (?) and... what you try to achieve by provided code? make min. you code by, for example, `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from user where Name=@name AND Password=@pwd;", connection); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nametextBox.Text); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", passwordTextBox.Text); SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); if(rdr.HasRows) { rdr.Read(); *match, check is user just a user or admin*} else {*not match, user or password incorrect*}`

Comment: Why do you have to loop in the value returned by your query. I assume that thee should only be 1 value to be returned. I suggest don't loop and do this logic `if txtusername = <UsernameValueFromQuery> andalso txtpassword = <PasswordValueFromQuery> then log in your user else dont login end` that is very simple